# how to create a range for the given data

Tags: sql, sql-server, date-range

If it is possible, can we create a range for the age and show the count for the same?

Let's say, the range is between 22 and 25 count: 3, range between 26 and 30 count : 5.

Below is the persons table for which I am trying to do this:

```
Age: 26 to 27, comments " post graduate"
Age: 28 to 30, comments "working and single"
Age: 31 to 33, comments " middle level manager and married"

Table name: persons

personid  lastname  firstname   age comments
1         Cardinal  Tom         22
2         prabhu    priya       33
3         bhandari  abhijeet    24
4         Harry     Bob         25
5         krishna   anand       29
6         hari      hara        31
7         ram       hara        27
8         kulkarni  manoj       35
9         joshi     santosh     28
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have got so far?

Comment: i couldn't think of anything..as i am new to sql. but i believe that this can be done by using the view.

Comment: What RDBM you are using ??

Comment: i am trying this in sql 2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN AGE >= 26 AND AGE <= 27 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS [total26To27]
      ,  COUNT(CASE WHEN AGE >= 28 AND AGE <= 30 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS [total28T30]
      ,  COUNT(CASE WHEN AGE >= 31 AND AGE <= 33 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS [total31T33]
FROM Persons
```

Comment: thanks ali, however this answer my last query raised. but there is small modification has to be done instead of "UPDATE TABLE persons" the correct is "UPDATE persons"...while running the last update..it is giving an error "Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 1
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated."

Comment: it works...but why have you used THEN 1??, instead of that can we try 1 or any other number? as I was trying to understand the logic, I have changed from 1 to 0, then 100, then 1000, but the answer remains the same.

Comment: I am not actually counting ages in the table I have used a CASE statement inside the count function, and telling count function to only count 1 when person's age is [range of age] else count nothing. and so on....

Comment: thanks for your help...can you suggest me a website or book from where i build my sql knowledge. I dont have any technical background.

Comment: google is your friend, youtube, there is lots of links , online tutorials videos and reading stuff and stick to stackover flow. you get to see the most real life problems here.